# How to configure libXML with CMake?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I have learned the basics of C++ programming and thought of ways how I could proceed, in order to practise. One thing that caught my interest was Web Scraping. Since I only knew BeautifulSoup, I searched for an alternative for C++ and found [libXML for C++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/), however I'm trying to install it but don't seem to get it to work, since I barely have an idea on how to configure a CMake file. I'm using CLion as an IDE and Windows as my operating system, if it matters. My project folder is

> C:\Users\Laurenz\Documents\Programming\untitled10

and the place where I've put the libXML library is

> C:\Users\Laurenz\Documents\Programming\untitled10\libXML

however, I think the "main" directory is the one below (since it contains most of the Source files), but I'm not sure which of both I need to include.

> C:\Users\Laurenz\Documents\Programming\untitled10\libXML\libxml++

I've searched around in the internet and found dozens of methods on how people include libraries, so I'm not sure which I need to use. What I currently have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(untitled10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled10 ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Users\\Laurenz\\Documents\\Programming\\untitled10\\libXML\\libxml++")
find_package(LibXML++ REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LibXML++_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LibXML++_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(untitled10 ${LIBS})
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error:By not providing "FindLibXML++.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "LibXML++", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LibXML++" with any of the following names:
  LibXML++Config.cmake   libxml++-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "LibXML++" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "LibXML++_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LibXML++" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Could someone tell me how to properly configure LibXML? And maybe someone knows some resources where I can learn how CMake files work, because it confuses me a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: You can start out simpler by just explicitly passing the include directory to `include_directories`.  You do not absolutely need `find_package()`.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much!